# RAID logs - What is the best way to organise them?

Tags: risk-management

First time using RAID logs as part of project delivery. I have found a template where Risks is separate from Issues done in Excel.

I am using it the following way:

1) RISKS - I specify all potential project risks in the risks tab in excel
2) ISSUES - if that RISK turns into an issue, I then log it, in the issues tab in excel.

Questions:

1) When do I mark the status of the risk and issue closed? Do I do this when the issue has been marked as closed?

Do I mark the issue as closed, if we have put a temporary solution to solve the problem but at a later date need to fix it properly

2) Is it good practice to have risks and issues in one tab, all templates I have seen they separate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a risk has materialised, it is no longer a risk, it is an issue. As you know. At that point the risk no longer exists and should be closed.

Personally I raise the Issue, and reference the Risk number it is derived from. Then I close the risk and reference the issue it has become within the closing comments.

There can be no clear definition of when an issue is closed, it is a matter for local management. However, if the issue still exists and you have just issued a workaround, then the issue still exists and should not be closed. If by providing the "fix" you have actually closed the issue, i.e. the observed fault/defect/impact has been removed, but has created other issues that need to be fixed in due course, then close the original issue and raise one or more new ones to reflect the current fault/defect/impact.

Your question two is somewhat off-topic as opinion-based. I have seen many systems and implementations of methods, where the Risks and the Issues are represented in the same physical location with designations of Risk or Issue; and I have worked with many that keep them physically separated (for example in two separate tabs of a spreadsheet). Personally I believe:

- they are two different entities with some common attributes but many different ones
- they often have different audiences, or at least different management and mitigation processes
- they have fundamentally different impacts- Risks are, by their very nature, in the future whereas Issues are impacting the project **now**

Accordingly I will always want to manage them in two separate lists where I have a choice. Others may have other opinions and practises.

Comment: Thank you Marv! Do you show your RAID to stakeholders?

Comment: You're welcome @bobo2000, but you should ask your question as a new question so that it can attract different answers and debates,